# Compile a file in ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v3)

Tags: asp.net, xsockets.net

I've got a ASP.NET Web Site project in which I want to use XSockets but when I create a custom class for XSockets the class is not being picked up by XSockets because it never gets compiled to a dll.

The class is in a file called MyChat.cs and once compiled XSockets should automatically pick it up. Does anyone here know how I can get that class to compile?

Answer (score 0):

Mark the MyChat.cs and look at properties.
Change build action from "none" to "compile".

Now VS should compile it into a assembly and XSockets will find the module/plugin.